# Using PDO to create a mysql query function, wont insert rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to get a grasp of using PDO, and I'm using some pre-made functions to make things simpler for when I want to do a query. First one connects, second runs the query.

Unfortunately it won't let me INSERT rows using dbquery(). SELECT works fine, just can't seem to get anything else to work.

Here's the code:

```
function dbConnect() 
  {
  global $dbh;

  $dbInfo['database_target'] = "localhost";
  $dbInfo['database_name'] = "mysqltester";
  $dbInfo['username'] = "root";
  $dbInfo['password'] = "password";

  $dbConnString = "mysql:host=" . $dbInfo['database_target'] . "; dbname=" . $dbInfo['database_name'];
  $dbh = new PDO($dbConnString, $dbInfo['username'], $dbInfo['password']);
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $error = $dbh->errorInfo();

  if($error[0] != "") 
    {
    print "<p>DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR:</p>";
    print_r($error);
    }
  }

function dbQuery($queryString) 
  {
  global $dbh;

  $query = $dbh->query($queryString);
  $i = 0;

  foreach ($query as $query2) 
    {
    $queryReturn[$i] = $query2;
    $i++;
    }

  if($i > 1) 
    {
    return $queryReturn;
    }
    else
    {
    return $queryReturn[0];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PDO::query](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) Only works with queries that return a result set (e.g. `SELECT`)

For INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE see [PDO::exec](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

If you are going to be inserting user provided data into your DBMS I strongly suggest using the prepared statement functionality of PDO to provide automatic escaping to prevent SQL injection.

e.g.

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tester1 (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array('James',25));
```

See [PDO::prepare](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [PDOStatement::execute](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: So use something like this?

$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO tester1 (name, age) VALUES ('James', 25)");

Comment: Yes. Though I strongly suggest using prepared statements when relevant, they handle the escaping for you. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. Prepared statements prevent sql injection?

Comment: by it's nature, Prepared statements submit two things to the DB.  First is the statement, it does not fill in the user input.  Then it submits the variables separately.  By separating the two, people can't put sql code into their inserts.  It's great for preventing SQL Injection attacks!